# Fix context menu on display area of Page

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

I am using [this context menu](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/). It works perfect with an odd behavior.
The top-left corner of the context menu always present at the position of mouse pointer.
Hence when user right-click at the almost bottom of the page the context menu gets hidden under the page and adds scroll bars to the page. To view this hidden menu user need to scroll the page down. It reset back the scroll bars after deselecting the Context menu.

For more clarification:
**This is a plain window:**
[image: Plain Window]

**After Right-Clicking on Item 5:**
[image: With context menu]

How can I avoid this and force the context menu to stay on the page no matter where user clicks?

Comment: No you cannot because that custom right click is different than context menu of browser.

Comment: is there any Context Menu Plugin Available in jquery to achieve the same?